# @SqlResultSetMapping is not working with date field

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date, spring-boot, jpa

I have following very straightforward code.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="getTestTable", classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(targetClass = someEntity.class, 
    columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name="some_date", type=Date.class)
    
    })
})
```

Query:

```
   getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT distinct some_date from test " );

    List<someList > list=query. getResultList();
```

Entity:
someEntity

```
       @Column(name = "some_date")
       @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
       private Date someDate;


     public someEntity(java.util.Date someDate) {
    super();
    this.someDate= someDate;
}
```

There is data in 'someDate' column and query is working fine on Sql-Editor, but when running above code "some_date" is always null.

What is wrong in this code? How should I get value for date?

I even converted the date format and declared field String in code but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** As you are using java.util.Date you should mark your date field with temporal type:

```
   @Column(name = "some_date")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
   private Date someDate;
```

**2)** Define your native query as NamedNativeQuery:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "testTableNativeQuery",
  query = "SELECT distinct some_date from test",
  resultSetMapping = "getTestTable")
```

**3)** Update your query execution:

```
getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("testTableNativeQuery", someEntity.class).getResultList();
```